# When $\langle f(x),y \rangle$ is a radical ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $f(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.

In the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, denote by $I_{f(x),y}$
the ideal generated by $f(x)$ and $y$,
$I_{f(x),y}:= \langle f(x),y \rangle$.

Recall that an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$ is called *radical*, if $a^n \in I$ implies that $a \in I$.

> When $\langle f(x),y \rangle$ is a radical ideal? (= for which $f(t) \in \mathbb{C}[t]$).

**Examples:**

**(1)** Take $f(t)=t^2$. Then $I_{x^2,y}=\langle x^2,y \rangle$
is not a radical ideal, since $x^2 \in I_{x^2,y}$ but $x \notin I_{x^2,y}$. Similarly, for $f(t)=t^m$, $I_{x^m,y}$ is not a radical ideal.

**(2)** For $f(t)=t$, the ideal $I_{x,y}$ is radical: $I_{x,y}$ is a maximal ideal (by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz), so it is a prime ideal (every maximal ideal is prime) and clearly a prime ideal is a radical ideal (follows immediately from the definitions).

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: $I$ is a radical ideal of $R$ if and only if $R/I$ is a reduced ring, i.e. it has no non-zero nilpotent element. Using this, $I$ is a radical ideal if and only if $\mathbb{C}[x]/(f(x))$ is a reduced ring.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Is it possible to obtain the exact form of such $f(t)$?

Comment: $f(t)$ splits into linear factors (since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed). From this it's easy to see that $f(t)$ is of the form $(t-a_1)\cdots (t-a_n)$ (assume the degree of $f$ is $n$) where $a_1, \cdots , a_n$ are *distinct* complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you again! I see why, for example, $f(t)=(t-a)(t-b)^2$ then $I$ is not radical, since $((t-a)(t-b))^2=(t-a)^2(t-b)^2 \in I$ but $(t-a)(t-b) \notin I$. Similarly, more generally, I see why if $f(t)=(t-c_1)^{m_1}\cdots(t-c_r)^{m_r}$ with at least one $m_j \geq 2$, $1 \leq j \leq r$, then $I_{f(x),y}$ is not radical. In other words, I see why: If $I_{f(x),y}$ is radical then $f$ is separable. But I am not sure about the other direction, namely, why if $f(t)$ is separable then $I_{f(x),y}$ is radical.

Comment: I have just noticed https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92391/when-does-a-polynomial-generate-a-radical-ideal?rq=1. But there the ideal is principal and here it is not.